# JADE agent communication

Tags: javascript, matlab, agents-jade

I am new in JADE programming. I am developing a multi-agent platform where there is a main container and under main container there are three agents: Interface Agent **(IE)**  and Agent **A** and Agent **B**.Interface agent **(IE)** receives input from outside software (ie: MATLAB/SIMULINK) and send it to Agent **A** and Agent **B** for further processing  inside agent platform and after receiving from them; send some sort of command signal back to MATLAB/SIMULINK again. Now I have a problem in agent platform to establish communication (ACL messaging) between interface agent **(IE)** ; Agent **A** and Agent **B**. The communication scnarios are in the following:

1. Agent **A** and Agent **B** are continously seeking infromation from Interfacing Agent (what are the inputs)?
2. Interface Agent **(IE)** sends  all the input received from MATLAB to Agent **A** and **B** as per their conversation ID.(send the input as per Agent Name)
3. Agent **A** recives the input; processes it and send it to Interface Agent; Agent **B** does the same as well. (Receiving, process and send reply)
4. Interface Agent **(IE)** send this data to MATLAB.

Now, Can some advise me how can I do the Agent t Agent communication using JADE ( scenario 1, 2 and 3).

ZN

Answer (score 1):

1.2.3, use ACLmessaging. Read the JADE online content and use FIPA-RequestInteraction protocol. Also called AchieveREInitiator and AchieveREResponder.

4, use a socket between Java and Matlab.